# Как запустить тесты из переименованной или не дефолтной папки?

Tags: php, yii2, тестирование, codeception

В *Yii2* структура папок для тестирования:

```
- tests
  - _data/
  - _output/
  - _support/
  - acceptance/
  - functional/
  - unit/
  - _bootstrap.php
  - acceptance.suite.yml.example
  - functional.suite.yml
  - unit.suite.yml
```

Я настроил тесты через *PhpStorm* и *Codeception*. Всё работает прекрасно. Тесты запускаются. Но я хочу сделать интеграционные тесты. Создал папку `integrational`, написал тест там. Запустил и...тесты не подхватились. То есть в целом эту папку даже не зашло тестирование.

Если переименовать папку `unit` в `unit2` или `functional` в `functional2`, то при запуске тестов возникает ошибка:

> Running with seed:
>
> In Bootstrap.php line 31:
> Bootstrap file /var/www/myproject/tests/functional/_bootstrap.php can't be
> loaded

То есть такое ощущение что пути где-то зашиты. Хотя в папке `vendor` у `Bootstrap.php` есть такие строки:

```
public function loadBootstrap(SuiteEvent $e)
{
    $settings = $e->getSettings();
    //....
    
    $bootstrap = $settings['path'] . $settings['bootstrap'];
    if (!is_file($bootstrap)) {
        throw new ConfigurationException("Bootstrap file $bootstrap can't be loaded");
    }

    require_once $bootstrap;
}
```

То есть какие-то настройки задаёт.

---

В общем: как и где можно задать настройки тестирования, чтобы можно было задать новую свою папку для тестирования. Или даже переименовать существующие, но без ругани. Например как создать папку `integrational` и запускать тесты включительно эту папку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ дал Дмитрий Елисеев на форуме: https://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?p=273945#p273945

Всё оказывается просто.

Сюиты подхватываются из `*.suite.yml` файлов.

Поэтому достаточно помимо файлов `unit.suite.yml` и `functional.suite.yml` добавить ещё `integrational.suite.yml` с настройками и тогда тесты начнут работать из папки `integrational` в том числе